How to calculate relative change when the starting value is negative
I have a temperature dataset with values at Time 1 and Time 2.
I need to show how much does the value change between the period, whether if increases or decreases, and how much, in relative terms.
To do so, I am trying to obtain the relative change (percentage) with the following expression:
$$
   x_{\Delta\%} =\frac{(x_{t2}-x_{t1})*100}{x_{t1}}
$$
I found it does not work when $x_{t1}<0$, as the sign of the solution is opposite to what it should be, two examples:
Example A:

$ x_{t1}=-10 $
$ x_{t2}=-8 $

Result obtained with the equation:
$x_{\Delta\%}= -20 \%$
When the actual result should be:
$x_{\Delta\%}= 20\%$
Example B:

$ x_{t1}=-10 $
$ x_{t2}=-12 $

Result obtained with the equation:
$x_{\Delta\%}= 20 \%$
When the actual result should be:
$x_{\Delta\%}= -20\%$
Is there another equation I could apply for this situation?

Actually, is the same problem.

It depends on what you're applying it to conceptually.  If there's a 20% increase in losses, the absolute value of the loss (represented by a negative number) will increase and its value (as profit) will decrease.  The opposite is true if there's a 20% decrease in losses.  Remember that a positive number times a negative is a negative, so 20/100 * -10 = -2 (i.e. -2 is 20% of -10).  But think of what you're applying it to conceptually, then apply the correct sign for it.

In particular when working with temperatures, for example, from -10° to -8° is an increase of 2°.

@Filippo Here's a food for thought: from -10 Celsius to 0 Celsius, the percentage increase is 100%. In Fahrenheit, though, the percentage increase is 129%. This shows that the conversion between C and F is of correspondence rather than equality, otherwise both computations would give the exact same percentage increase.

Interesting @ryang- thank you

Hint: For $x<0$, the values increase towards zero and decrease away from zero. What will that do the percentages?

The negative number analogue would be $$x_{\Delta \%} = \dfrac {|x_{t_1}| - |x_{t_2}|}{|x_{t_1}|} \ , x_{t_1}<0 \text { and }  x_{t_2}<0 $$

